# Pandas: order values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have data:

```
Third party unique identifier   Qsex    Qage    Qfamilystatus       QeducationSingle    Qincomeevaluation   Qjobstatus  QRuCitySize QRuDistrict Qcountry
9ea3e3cb6719f3d336d324c446f486bd    1   32  1       5   1   1   1   1
cb570bb986808a5f4d2629287297b902    2   25          5   2   1   1   1
78b3a44eb7c7f7c687ffbcfed57647a4    1   30          4   1   3   6   1
1c728b223a4c2c267f3a3630b4a63f6e    2   45          4   1   1   1   1
8852ecd198fddfa557186c863f2c6fdf    2   41          4   1   7   7   1
1adc146b9ec35f7c632902f480d7e95c    1   70          5   3   1   1   1
0fb0c903a6b2b68f1b0a7cd1962f353c    1   29          5   1   5   7   1
```

And another df:

```
QRuDistrict 1   ЦФО
QRuDistrict 2   ЮФО
QRuDistrict 3   СЗФО
QRuDistrict 4   ДВФО
QRuDistrict 5   СФО
QRuDistrict 6   УФО
QRuDistrict 7   ПФО
QRuDistrict 8   СКФО
QRuDistrict 9   Крымский ФО
```

I try to replace values from first df to data from second and count percentage and write that to `excel`.

I use:

```
d = (df_1[df_1['sign']=='Qcountry'].set_index('number')['result'].to_dict())
df['Country'] = df.Qcountry.map(d)
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.Country, df.Qcountry, margins=True)
df3 = np.round(df2[["All"]] / df['Country'].count() * 100, 2).rename(columns={"All": '%'})
country = pd.concat([df2[["All"]], df3], axis=1)
less = country[country['%'] < 5]

country = country[country['%'] >= 5]
country['All'] = ((all_users * df3.divide(100)).astype(int))
country['%'] = country['%'].astype(str) + '%'
country.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=48, startcol=4)
```

and get:

```
Federal Districts   Россия  
N   %
ДВФО    131 5.33%
Крымский ФО 11  0.48%
ПФО 416 16.91%
СЗФО    420 17.09%
СКФО    43  1.75%
СФО 259 10.53%
УФО 208 8.48%
ЦФО 764 31.08%
ЮФО 205 8.35%
Total   2461    100.0%
```

But I want to get sequence like in a second dataframe.
I want to get:

```
Federal Districts   Россия  
N   %
ЦФО 764 31.08%
ЮФО 205 8.35%
СЗФО    420 17.09%
ДВФО    131 5.33%
СФО 259 10.53%
УФО 208 8.48%
ПФО 416 16.91%
СКФО    43  1.75%
Крымский ФО 11  0.48%
Total   2461    100.0%
```

How can I sort that in this order?

Comment: did you look at [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)?

Comment: just use the second column from the second dataframe. append it and sort your data using that since it goes from 1-9 in the order you require.

Comment: @EdChum if I understand true, I can use that to numeric values, but I don't know, how can I specify to sort like in anoter dataframe

Comment: @Ev.Kounis i try `df = df.sort_values('Qcountry')` before `df['Country'] = df.Qcountry.map(d)
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.Country, df.Qcountry, margins=True)
df3 = np.round(df2[["All"]] / df['Country'].count() * 100, 2).rename(columns={"All": '%'})` but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by second DataFrame, but is necessary add last item `['Total']` to `list`:

```
print (df)
               a            b
0  QRuDistrict 1          ЦФО
1  QRuDistrict 2          ЮФО
2  QRuDistrict 3         СЗФО
3  QRuDistrict 4         ДВФО
4  QRuDistrict 5          СФО
5  QRuDistrict 6          УФО
6  QRuDistrict 7          ПФО
7  QRuDistrict 8         СКФО
8  QRuDistrict 9  Крымский ФО

print (df1)
            Federal Districts  Россия  
                            N         %
ДВФО                      131     5.33%
Крымский ФО                11     0.48%
ПФО                       416    16.91%
СЗФО                      420    17.09%
СКФО                       43     1.75%
СФО                       259    10.53%
УФО                       208     8.48%
ЦФО                       764    31.08%
ЮФО                       205     8.35%
Total                    2461    100.0%
```

```
idx = df.b.tolist() + ['Total']
print (idx)
['ЦФО', 'ЮФО', 'СЗФО', 'ДВФО', 'СФО', 'УФО', 'ПФО', 'СКФО', 'Крымский ФО', 'Total']
df1 = df1.reindex(idx)
print (df1)
            Federal Districts  Россия  
                            N         %
ЦФО                       764    31.08%
ЮФО                       205     8.35%
СЗФО                      420    17.09%
ДВФО                      131     5.33%
СФО                       259    10.53%
УФО                       208     8.48%
ПФО                       416    16.91%
СКФО                       43     1.75%
Крымский ФО                11     0.48%
Total                    2461    100.0%
```

---

If use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), ordering is different:

```
df1 = df1.sort_index(ascending=False)
print (df1)
            Federal Districts  Россия  
                            N         %
ЮФО                       205     8.35%
ЦФО                       764    31.08%
УФО                       208     8.48%
СФО                       259    10.53%
СКФО                       43     1.75%
СЗФО                      420    17.09%
ПФО                       416    16.91%
Крымский ФО                11     0.48%
ДВФО                      131     5.33%
Total                    2461    100.0%
```

EDIT by comment:

I changed column names and it seems you need only values of column `sign`, where first column `number` contains `QRuDistrict`. Then you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and mask with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df)
          number         sign
0  QRuDistrict 1          ЦФО
1  QRuDistrict 2          ЮФО
2  QRuDistrict 3         СЗФО
3  QRuDistrict 4         ДВФО
4  QRuDistrict 5          СФО
5  QRuDistrict 6          УФО
6  QRuDistrict 7          ПФО
7  QRuDistrict 8         СКФО
8  QRuDistrict 9  Крымский ФО

idx = df.ix[df.number.str.contains('QRuDistrict'), 'sign'].tolist() + ['Total']
print (idx)
['ЦФО', 'ЮФО', 'СЗФО', 'ДВФО', 'СФО', 'УФО', 'ПФО', 'СКФО', 'Крымский ФО', 'Total']
```

Comment: Can you say, if my `df` contain not only `QRuDistrict` in the first column, how can I get only `QRuDistrict` from there?

Comment: I try `idx = df['b' == 'QRuDistrict '].tolist() + ['Total']` but it return `KeyError: False`

Comment: What are columns of your second DataFrame? print (df.columns) ?

Comment: Index([u'sign', u'number', u'result'], dtype='object') and I try `idx = df['result' == 'QRuDistrict '].tolist() + ['Total']`

Comment: Thank you. So first column with `QRuDistrict 1`, `QRuDistrict 2` is `result` ? And what is name of column with `ЦФО`, `ЮФО` ? `number` or `sign` ?

Comment: Or `QRuDistrict 1`, `QRuDistrict 2` is `number` and `ЦФО`, `ЮФО`  is `sign` ?

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have reputation to upvote your answer. When I have 15 and more, I upvote your answer)